# Minimizing the expected value of number of jumps in a jumping competition

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Two runners compete head-to-head on a straight line in a pit jumping competition. There are infinitely many pits, each of length $L$. Each runner tries to jump over every pit and the competition ends when one of them jumps and falls into a pit. The runners never get tired and the probability that a runner will jump over a pit is $\dfrac{1}{2^L}$ independent of which pit it is.

**Question**
If the competition ends in a tie, we send the runners back to the starting line and we repeat this process until we have a winner. What should be the value of $L$ if we want to minimize the expected value of the number of jumps of the runners?

First of all, I don't understand how if the competition ends in a tie we send them back to the starting line, this is an infinitely long race? So I interpreted this problem as there is no tie, which has probability $1-\dfrac{1-2^L}{1+2^L}$. If $X$ is the random variable for the number of jumps, then $P(X=n)=\left(1-\dfrac{1-2^L}{1+2^L}\right)\left(\left(\dfrac{1}{2^L}\right)^{n-1}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^L}\right)+\left(\dfrac{1}{2^L}\right)^{n-1}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^L}\right)\right)$. Using this the expected value I find doesn't make sense to me. I'm not even sure if I should multiply the right hand side with the probability of no tie.

Comment: How can the competition end in a tie if there are infinitely many pits to be jumped? The only way to tie then is if they both lose at the same time, no? Otherwise, they jump forever until one loses.